# Understanding Cassandra message latency metric

Tags: cassandra

I'm trying to understand how to use the `org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=Messaging` metric. I setup 3 datacenters with 1 node each. When I measure the metric, for each node I get 2 cross-datacenter metrics and 1 cross-node latency metric as follows (for node in DC-2)

```
org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=Messaging,name=dc3-Latency
5.3387457013878636E7
org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=Messaging,name=CrossNodeLatency
1.1471964354991291E8
org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=Messaging,name=dc1-Latency
1.6108579786605054E8
```

However, I have no processes using the cluster currently. Is Cassandra doing a dummy write to measure this metric? Also, what does the cross-node latency metric mean here, each DC contains only one node.

Comment: It looks like latency metrics are measured in microseconds according to this documentation: https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/metrics.html

Answer (score 3):

The metric records incoming latency from all things using the message service. The message service is used for read/writes but its also used for streaming and gossip. Gossip fires every 1 second between all the nodes so this is probably dominating it in your situation. Also some tables may be written to (system_distributed, system_traces, and some dse tables if using dse) with even a pretty idle system in some situations.

Whenever a message is sent from one node to another, it attaches a timestamp to it along with some versioning information. The first thing the receiving system will do (ignoring the obvious os/socket/etc) more or less is compare that timestamp to "now". This is what drives the metric. It will then look at the datacenter the source is from to determine which metrics to increment by how much.