# How to monitor Cassandra replication lag?

Tags: cassandra, monitoring, latency

I have a Cassandra cluster setup with datacenter, each datacenter has a 3nodes. While doing load testing on it the data is replication from datacenter1 to datacenter2.

But is there any way by which I can monitor the replication lag/latency while data is getting replicated from dc1 to dc2?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding Cassandra message latency metric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41433502/understanding-cassandra-message-latency-metric)

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at this [Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11569) ticket. It describes a new metrics for cross dc latency for Cassandra 3.8 and above.