# Cassandra latency check between DC1 and DC2

Tags: database, time, cassandra, replication, latency

I have a 5 node multi DC Cassandra cluster where I'm trying to determine the time taken for the data to reach/replicate from DC1 to DC2

- 2 nodes are Onprem - DC1
- 3 nodes on Cloud - DC2

When I write data to OnPrem nodes, how much time does it take to replicate to cloud node and ready available for reads.

Comment: look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41433502/understanding-cassandra-message-latency-metric